# Unexpected result using Interlocked

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this code

```
int j = -1;
Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
{
    Console.Write("i= " +i);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref j);
    Console.Write(" j= " + j);
    Console.WriteLine();
});
```

After running it, I was expecting to have the values of `i` somehow randomly displayed, not in a ascending order, but for the values of `j` variable I was expecting to have them all the time in an ascending order.

So now I have this output at some point:

[image]

So there is a `j= 78` between values `93` and `94`, is this right ? Could some of you please explain me why I have this value here and not between `77` and `79`, is this because Console.Write method is not thread safe ?

Are values of `j` variable given (as I was expecting) in ascending order, and the output `j = 78` is just a glitch of `Console.Write` method since it is not thread safe?

Comment: You are not using any locks in your code when you print. What is your actual question?

Comment: You should really use/print the _return value_ of `Interlocked.Increment`, to get a real atomic increment since `j` could be changed by another thread while you're using it while the return value won't change once it's returned.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Doing that would mean that each value would be printed exactly once, without any duplicates or skipped numbers, but it wouldn't guarantee that they're printed in order.

Comment: @Servy Oh, I do get that, just wanted to point out the somewhat more subtle bug Nayuki didn't already point out :)

Comment: @Nayuki  My basic question is, why I have "j=78" between 93 and 94 values of j variable.

Comment: @user5631730 The thread with j=78 would seem to have been stopped for a while to let another thread/process run. There is nothing strange with parallel threads not printing everything in sequence.

Comment: One rule of thumb I use is "if you require things to happen in strict sequence, you should probably think twice about why you're running them in parallel in the first place."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> for the values of "j" variable I was expecting to have them all the time in an ascending order.

Not only does it not guarantee that, it's not even guaranteed to print every number exactly once.  It can print a number multiple times, or not at all.  A thread can increment the number (let's say from 0 to 1), then pause, let another thread runs, which can then increment the number again (to 2), print it, then pause, let the first thread resume, and print the same value again (2, in this case).

Likewise, a thread can resolve the variable to a value, then pause, let another thread increment it dozens of times, printing it as it goes, then let the original thread resume, printing the value it pulled from the variable long before all of those increments.

Fundamentally your increment of the variable and printing of the value isn't an atomic operation.  You would need to explicitly synchronize that block of code to prevent multiple threads from being in the  middle of those two operations at the same time in order to have the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing `Interlocked.Increment` guarantees is that no two threads will increment`j` at the same time. Outside of that there's no way to determine which thread will write to the console first. 
It looks like you're experimenting and the sequence doesn't really matter to you. That's good, because it's a nice example of how multithreaded apps can behave in a non-deterministic way. In this case it works well if you want these things to happen, just not if you want them to happen in a predictable order.

This wouldn't fix `i`, but you could try

```
var k = Interlocked.Increment(ref j);
Console.Write(" k= " + k);
Console.WriteLine();
```

That still won't guarantee sequence but it should get you all the unique values.